# automake output binaries bigger than the command-line compiled bins

Tags: c++, autoconf, automake

For a small project I'm developing, I've been using simple compilation via command-line. However, as it became bigger, I decided to learn and use autoconf and automake to compile it.

After some configuration, I successfully built using automake. However I noted that the size of the output binary file was bigger than using g++ via command-line. I tried using static and dynamic libs and the result was the same.

I've also tried a simple hello world and it was also bigger with automake than with command-line compilation.

So, I tried to run `objdump -h`: the command-line compiled returned 27 sections, and on the other side the automake compiled returned the same 27 sections plus 7 sections called debug_aranges ,debug_info ,debug_abbrev, debug_line, debug_loc, debug_ranges. So I'm obviously inclined to think it's something related with debug.

So, anyone knows what this sections are for, if they are necessary and how to a get rid of then so the executables are smaller for distribution.

Comment: I do not know automake well, but is seems like you are including debug symbols through your automake script. Try to find the automake option that disables that.

Comment: Pursuant to that - try `strip`ping the binary; is it still any larger afterwards?

Comment: yes! After using strip on both, they got the same size. Sorry I didn't knew about this command. I've also realized the "problem" was that automake automatically puts the -g parameter in g++ during compilation which is in fact a debug symbol as dtech said. Thanks for helping.

Comment: automake compiles with CFLAGS defined by the user a configure time, and the default CFLAGS setting is "-g -O2".  You should not change your Makefile.am to change this, but assign CFLAGS when you run configure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just invoke `make install-strip` when you install the binaries and `install` will strip them during the install process.